# Any continuous group homomorphism from $\mathbb{R}$ to $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$

Tags: analysis, representation-theory, lie-groups

Any continuous group homomorphism $\phi$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ is of the form $\phi (t)=exp(tX)$  for some $X\in M(n,\mathbb{C})$. Can anyone give hints for the proof of this fact? I consider the case $n=1$. But I cannot see why $\phi(\mathbb{R})$ must be on the unit circle. Thanks!

Comment: It need not. eg if $X=1$ it will not be. Hint: Take $X=\phi(1)$ and use that $\phi$ is a group homomorphism to extend to $\mathbb{Z}$ and then to $\mathbb{Q}$.